# How to upgrade Ubuntu via usb boot without loosing existing program and configuration

Tags: upgrade

My old Ubuntu version 14.04 has problem with network-manager. I'm a normal user with a backup storage for my important data so I decided to upgrade directly to 16.04 via a bootable usb instead of reverting network-manager version and wait for next fix.

In my previous experience of upgrading Ubuntu through Internet, I have to switch between multiple releases, and all my applications and configurations in /etc is not removed.

However, this upgrade from usb boot remove all my applications and their configurations.

What lost is lost. I was going to reduce the effect to me next time by divide a partition for the OS only and the application (with its configuration) is on another partition (It's my pure thinking from my experience with Windows). However, again I recognize that I cannot mount /etc to any partion which means next upgrade will still remove the configuration. Also I'm not sure which partition will be kept untouch by installation since it left only /home directory not being removed.


So my question is: is it possible to upgrade Ubuntu OS only via bootable usb without loosing applications and configurations. If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 directly without losing anything. You can give it a try. System Setting > Softwares & Updates > Updates.

Select 'For Long Term Support Version'  at 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version'.

Now run the `sudo apt-get upgrade` from terminal and see updates are avail for you.

Comment: Previously, I have done that upgrade via Internet. Unfortunately, in my current case, network-manager is broken so no network available for apt-get to work. Hence, my question focus on upgrade Ubuntu without loosing applications (and its configuration) when using bootable usb.